# Server 500 Error - Laravel

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.1, server-error, http-status-code-500

I have developed my own website by using Laravel.It is working fine in Localhost.

So I have moved my files into live server(byethost.com). When I'm trying to access my site, I got an error (Server Error 500). I am new to this laravel.Please Any one help me to solve my problem.

**Note:** Moved all local files into public_html folder in server. then moved `public_html/public` files to `public_html` directory in server.And also changed path in app file.

**Code:**

```
require __ DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __ DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Free hosting URL:  [www.sankaran.bytehost15.com](http://sankaran.byethost15.com/nano/)

Log file:
sankaran.byethost15.com [22/Dec/2015:06:48:15 -0500] 106.51.135.213 - - "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 302 208 "http://sankaran.byethost15.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"

sankaran.byethost15.com [22/Dec/2015:06:48:43 -0500] 106.51.135.213 - - "GET /images/slider/bg1.jpg HTTP/1.0" 302 208 "http://sankaran.byethost15.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"

sankaran.byethost15.com [22/Dec/2015:07:47:59 -0500] 106.51.135.213 - - "GET /index.php HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"

sankaran.byethost15.com [22/Dec/2015:07:47:59 -0500] 106.51.135.213 - - "GET /index.php HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"

sankaran.byethost15.com [22/Dec/2015:07:48:18 -0500] 106.51.135.213 - - "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 200 - "http://sankaran.byethost15.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"

sankaran.byethost15.com [22/Dec/2015:07:48:44 -0500] 106.51.135.213 - - "GET /fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3 HTTP/1.0" 302 208 "http://sankaran.byethost15.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"

sankaran.byethost15.com [22/Dec/2015:07:49:12 -0500] 106.51.135.213 - - "GET /sankaran/ HTTP/1.0" 302 208 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"

sankaran.byethost15.com [22/Dec/2015:08:47:32 -0500] 106.51.135.213 - - "GET /nano/ HTTP/1.0" 500 - "[Server 500 Error - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416686/server-500-error-laravel)" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"

sankaran.byethost15.com [22/Dec/2015:08:47:57 -0500] 41.189.90.42 - - "GET /first/ HTTP/1.0" 200 1321 "http://sankaran.byethost15.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"

sankaran.byethost15.com [22/Dec/2015:08:48:24 -0500] 119.160.193.114 - - "GET /nano/?ckattempt=1 HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"

sankaran.byethost15.com [22/Dec/2015:08:48:24 -0500] 119.160.193.114 - - "GET /nano/?ckattempt=1 HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"

sankaran.byethost15.com [22/Dec/2015:09:47:28 -0500] 80.252.79.186 - - "GET /nano/?ckattempt=1 HTTP/1.0" 500 - "http://sankaran.byethost15.com/nano/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"

sankaran.byethost15.com [22/Dec/2015:09:47:47 -0500] 96.225.60.66 - - "GET /nano/?ckattempt=1 HTTP/1.0" 500 - "http://sankaran.byethost15.com/nano/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36"

Comment: You need to give read/write permissions to the `storage/*` directory and `bootstrap/cache` directory.

Comment: Can you please check error log for same?

Comment: probably some php extension you have in your project that isn't installed on byethost.com. And check error log for sure like mentioned above

Comment: Firstly, please comment / remove the .htaccess file temporary then check. Still if you face the same then check the error log.

Comment: I think the logs will have the error. So you can either go through them or paste them in the question as that will give a better picture.

Comment: ya thanks all. I go through my log file. but I can understand it. please help me to find out my problem.

Comment: @SanKaRan the log you pasted is access log, not the error log, those file not exist won't give you 500 status.

Comment: Oopps..sry @phoenix. Now chack it.

Comment: This is apache or nginx? which log file are you checking?

Comment: you are asking either this access log file or laravel log file?

Comment: The http server's error log is the first place you need to check, then check php-fpm's error log (if you are using php-fpm), then check laravel's. You need to find the reason caused 500 server error, because it can be anything. after that you can ask how to solve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98722/discussion-between-san-ka-ran-and-phoenix).

Answer (score 0):

You need to give read/write permissions.

On Laravel 5.2.* open up terminal (on mac) `cd` into `/storage` and run the following command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

You will be asked to enter your administrator password, do this and then go refresh the page. You should see **Laravel 5**